# Ornithoid character

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I read a book in the 1980s about a woman ambassador to a planet that was inhabited by ornithoids. The main character formed a close relationship to a male ornithoid. I wish I could remember the name and the author, because I'd like to read it again.

Comment: How bird like we're the aliens?  Can you remember any plot points?

Comment: Deleted dupe.  Pls remove

Comment: They were more human than birdlike. I don't remember the plot, but there were mercenaries, and poisionings. The heroine had "gone native". It's been so long since I read it, but I just remember that I liked it and want to read it again.

Comment: Mary Gentle's Golden Witchbreed? Your comment about the ambassador going native made me think of this book.

Comment: Oh! I believe that was it! I'd been thinking that the word "witch" was in the title somewhere. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MelitaKennedy Can you post this as an answer, because this shows up in a search for unanswered questions, which it basically isn't!

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't sure at the time that I had the answer, but the original poster says yes, so...

[Mary Gentle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Gentle)'s *Golden Witchbreed*

There's a sequel, *Ancient Light*, but it has a very downbeat ending. You should think hard about whether you want to track the sequel down.